# Rewrite simple url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would rewrite a very simple url

```
http://localhost/?page=me
```

to

```
http://localhost/me
```

I have try this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

But not work (error 500).

---

And like this, it work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

but the link is `http://localhost/me/`, i want remove the last `/`
an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some conditions to prevent the rewrite engine from looping. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Unlike the second rule where the URI matched is always non-empty, the `/` won't get matched again and continue to loop.

Comment: it is true, when i trying other solution, i get an redirection error... your code work and is very usefull !! thanks for explanation Jon Lin =)